# How to display a database from assets folder?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I want to display a database (values.db) from assets folder into a table or list in the last activity.
The database is already finished and needs no more input.

While going through the activities which are before the table, you can select the filters which will be stored as Strings. These Strings will be used for the filtering of the DB.

Is it right to store them as a String? Could there be an more professional way?

And finally:
What is the right way to display the data?

Comment: What is a "database" in this context? The way you're using the word doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner. It's an SQLite file with one table inside.

Answer (score 1):

If the database is only to be **read** then you can open it from the assets folder.

You would typically use a **ListView** or a **RecyclerView** to display the rows (data from the database). This would require extracting the data via a **Cursor**, the Cursor being created by querying the database via either the **rawQuery** or **query** SQLite methods. The **query** could/would include the filtering.

However, if you want to store the filters then you would either need, another database, use shared preferences or use a file.

Using the original/source database to store filters would need update access to the database and thus require that it be copied from the assets folder to a folder (often **data/data/package/databases**) (**SQLiteAssetHelper** can be used to simplify copying from the assets folder).

Quite a few keywords, as highlighted, that could help you to investigate further.

Comment: This helped me a lot, thank you!